# How to Run Appium on ios Simulator 8.x/7.x

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am trying to do the automation using Appium on ios simulators.
My config is:

```
OS version: 10.10.x
Appium: 1.4.0
Xcode: 6.3.2
```

and caps for appium is:

```
automationName = "Appium"
platformName = "iOS"
platformVersion = "8.3"
deviceName = "iPhone 5s"
app = "/Users/skaram200/Desktop/ios_build/XfinityMyAccount_6.3.app"
```

When I run the appium it is giving me an error:

````
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/xcode6.3/Xcode6.3.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/xcode6.3/Xcode6.3.2.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator)" /Users/skaram200/Desktop/ios_build/XfinityMyAccount_6.3.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/skaram200/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-4d92d75355d74eeb.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Users/skaram200/Documents/workspace/appium_1/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd6/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Users/skaram200/Documents/workspace/appium_1/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd6"}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-09-10 10:47:20.672 instruments[36855:1272282] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST] Waiting for device to boot...
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Unable to install app with path: /Users/skaram200/Desktop/ios_build/XfinityMyAccount_6.3.app: "(null)"
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files
info: Executing: xcrun simctl erase F54870E7-17FD-4A07-B6EE-1636F6AB5757 with timeout 2000
info: Executing: xcrun simctl erase F54870E7-17FD-4A07-B6EE-1636F6AB5757 with timeout 2000
info: [debug] Cleaning app data files
warn: Applications directory /Users/skaram200/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F54870E7-17FD-4A07-B6EE-1636F6AB5757/data/Applications doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Users/skaram200/Documents/workspace/appium_1/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/skaram200/Documents/workspace/appium_1/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
```
````

Please let me know, how can I resolve these errors and start automating on ios simulators using appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a successfull Build without an error.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer. This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to pass the **--default-device or -dd as true** for simulators and need to specify the **--bundleID** of the app. And **we need to have debug .ipa or .app file to do automation.**

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: I provided the bundleId and --dd as true but still same error persists.
``` [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Unable to install app with path: /Users/skaram200/Desktop/ios_build/XfinityMyAccount_6_3.app: "(null)"
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253   ```

Comment: The states that app path is not proper to install and it's getting null as input. Please check and give proper app path.

Comment: I moved build in another folder and tried but still same issue. Also, I provided the same path where build is created and stored. But still same issue.

Comment: There might be some problem with simulators, Please try to run code once in real device and share the logs.

Comment: I got the problem, it was with building the BUILD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Cordova, got some issues with that as well, this is what Idid in order to generate the .app:

```
cordova build ios --emulator
```

That's it, after that I was able to use Appium and push the .app to the simulator.

I hope it helps somebody else!